# Axes missing when plotting in matplotlib using vispy as backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqtgraph, vispy

I have been watching the development of the python graphing library [vispy](http://vispy.org/) with excitement.  I just discovered that I can use vispy as a backend to matplotlib, which is great because I am plotting hundreds of thousands of points.  I ran the [example](http://api.vispy.org/en/latest/examples/basics/plotting/mpl_plot.html) and I noticed there are no axes.  I also ran the following code.

```
import vispy.mpl_plot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

The axes were present until the `plt.show()` command, and they disappeared.  I understand that the vispy project is under development, but plotting with axes would be extremely valuable to me, so I was wondering how I could do this.  Also, less urgently, the border around the graph becomes huge.  Is there a way to shrink the border?

Comment: Ths mplt_plot functionality is still in development and incomplete. For one, it does not draw axes.

Comment: That would explain why I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Axes are indeed of topmost priority in VisPy, hopefully we'll do it within the next two months. There is already some code in glumpy that we can "simply" port to VisPy.

Answer (score 0):

The support for the matplotlib backend was dropped in version 0.5:
https://github.com/vispy/vispy/pull/1224